# How can I compile and execute Java from command line adding external Jar and using file's full path?

Tags: java, bash

I created a simple script for running a little java program. Everything was working well until I added an external JAR. Now I'm not able to make it run properly. If I run it from Eclipse everything works well. The project is in  `/home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación página`  and the structure is something like this:

```
Comprobacion
    |----lib
            jsoup-1.8.3.jar
    |----src
        |----main
            App.java
    |----Referenced libraries
        jsoup-1.8.3.jar
```

My script is in `/home/eneko/Documents` and this is what it contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

javac -cp /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/main/Main.java
java -cp .:/home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/main/Main
```

When I run the script it gives me: "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal .home.eneko.workspace.Comprobación página.src.main.Main".
It means "Error: main class .home.eneko.workspace.Comprobación página.src.main.Main not found or not loaded" 
I found some answers but they all execute commands from the same folder where the Main.java file is and I want to know why I can't add external libraries in this way.
Before adding the external library my script contained this:

```
#!/bin/bash

javac -cp /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/main/Main.java
java -cp /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/main/ Main
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
java -cp /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar:/home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src main.Main
```

Comment: Thank you Solver. I received the same error but changing the last part it resolved my problem. I'll edit your answer and mark it.